# Saving migration to chain.insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

It looks like the contract was deployed well on mainnet
However, eventually this error occurs

`Saving migration to chain.insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Does it mean that the migration was not saved?

Does it mean the contract should be re-deployed again?
Or it is possible to fix?

Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL**
truffle.js

```
live: {
    provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`)
    },
    network_id: '1',
    //gas: 8000000,
    gasPrice: 140000000000,
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the migration has failed.
This error means you have insufficient Ethers to deploy your contract, you should therefore redeploy with the correct amount of ETH.

Comment: thanks! Does it mean I should have more ETH, or should I change my truffle.js also. E.g: currently I have gasPrice: 140000000000, added in ticket description more details.

Comment: You can do both. Your gas price is currently at 140 gwei. You can see here https://ethgasstation.info/ the average current gas price. It is 70gwei at the time of this post so you can decrease your gas price in truffle.js to match the average market price.  If it not sufficient, get more ETH.

Comment: Got it thanks, btw just wonder the contract was deployed well but the output about saving migrations was strange. I'm able to see the contract on Etherscan. Wonder could it be just some truffle issue with logs/messaging...? Or could I have issue with following migrations in future?

Comment: Are you able to interact with you contract ? If yes, that's mean it is deployed but that's would be surprising regarding the Truffle error.

Comment: Yes I was able to interact with the contract, thanks!